# LTspice - Effect of source inductance on the gate to source voltage

Tags: ltspice, simulation

I was trying to simulate the effect of source inductance on the gate to source voltage and it seems that I have a convergence problem. I do not understand why the simulation is not working? I would really appreciate to understand what is happening inside the simulator when this happens...

Here is the simulation:

[image]

Here are the results:

[image]

Here is the txt file:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 10632 1524
WIRE 3680 -304 3328 -304
WIRE 4448 -304 3680 -304
WIRE 4528 -304 4448 -304
WIRE 4704 -304 4592 -304
WIRE 7600 -304 7248 -304
WIRE 8368 -304 7600 -304
WIRE 8448 -304 8368 -304
WIRE 8624 -304 8512 -304
WIRE 1008 -288 656 -288
WIRE 1056 -288 1008 -288
WIRE 1200 -288 1136 -288
WIRE 1376 -288 1264 -288
WIRE 2336 -288 1984 -288
WIRE 2400 -288 2336 -288
WIRE 2528 -288 2480 -288
WIRE 2704 -288 2592 -288
WIRE 5632 -288 5280 -288
WIRE 6400 -288 5632 -288
WIRE 6480 -288 6400 -288
WIRE 6656 -288 6544 -288
WIRE 3328 -272 3328 -304
WIRE 7248 -272 7248 -304
WIRE 656 -256 656 -288
WIRE 1984 -256 1984 -288
WIRE 5280 -256 5280 -288
WIRE 3328 -160 3328 -192
WIRE 7248 -160 7248 -192
WIRE 656 -144 656 -176
WIRE 1984 -144 1984 -176
WIRE 5280 -144 5280 -176
WIRE 3680 -128 3680 -304
WIRE 4448 -128 4448 -304
WIRE 7600 -128 7600 -304
WIRE 8368 -128 8368 -304
WIRE 1008 -112 1008 -288
WIRE 2336 -112 2336 -288
WIRE 5632 -112 5632 -288
WIRE 6400 -112 6400 -288
WIRE 3088 -48 2992 -48
WIRE 3232 -48 3168 -48
WIRE 3360 -48 3232 -48
WIRE 3472 -48 3440 -48
WIRE 3632 -48 3472 -48
WIRE 4096 -48 3952 -48
WIRE 4320 -48 4176 -48
WIRE 4400 -48 4320 -48
WIRE 4704 -48 4704 -304
WIRE 7008 -48 6912 -48
WIRE 7152 -48 7088 -48
WIRE 7280 -48 7152 -48
WIRE 7456 -48 7360 -48
WIRE 7552 -48 7456 -48
WIRE 8016 -48 7872 -48
WIRE 8240 -48 8096 -48
WIRE 8320 -48 8240 -48
WIRE 8624 -48 8624 -304
WIRE 672 -32 400 -32
WIRE 848 -32 752 -32
WIRE 960 -32 848 -32
WIRE 1376 -32 1376 -288
WIRE 2000 -32 1776 -32
WIRE 2208 -32 2080 -32
WIRE 2288 -32 2208 -32
WIRE 2704 -32 2704 -288
WIRE 5040 -32 4944 -32
WIRE 5184 -32 5120 -32
WIRE 5312 -32 5184 -32
WIRE 5504 -32 5392 -32
WIRE 5584 -32 5504 -32
WIRE 6048 -32 5904 -32
WIRE 6304 -32 6128 -32
WIRE 6352 -32 6304 -32
WIRE 6656 -32 6656 -288
WIRE 2992 -16 2992 -48
WIRE 6912 -16 6912 -48
WIRE 1776 0 1776 -32
WIRE 4944 0 4944 -32
WIRE 400 32 400 -32
WIRE 3232 32 3232 -48
WIRE 3952 32 3952 -48
WIRE 3952 32 3232 32
WIRE 7152 32 7152 -48
WIRE 7872 32 7872 -48
WIRE 7872 32 7152 32
WIRE 4448 48 4448 -32
WIRE 5184 48 5184 -32
WIRE 5904 48 5904 -32
WIRE 5904 48 5184 48
WIRE 8368 48 8368 -32
WIRE 3536 64 3456 64
WIRE 3680 64 3680 -32
WIRE 3680 64 3616 64
WIRE 7440 64 7328 64
WIRE 7600 64 7600 -32
WIRE 7600 64 7520 64
WIRE 5488 80 5408 80
WIRE 5632 80 5632 -16
WIRE 5632 80 5568 80
WIRE 2992 112 2992 64
WIRE 3456 112 3456 64
WIRE 3456 112 2992 112
WIRE 4032 112 3456 112
WIRE 4448 112 4448 48
WIRE 4448 112 4112 112
WIRE 1776 128 1776 80
WIRE 2336 128 2336 -16
WIRE 2336 128 1776 128
WIRE 4944 128 4944 80
WIRE 5408 128 5408 80
WIRE 5408 128 4944 128
WIRE 5984 128 5408 128
WIRE 6400 128 6400 -16
WIRE 6400 128 6064 128
WIRE 6912 128 6912 64
WIRE 7328 128 7328 64
WIRE 7328 128 6912 128
WIRE 7904 128 7328 128
WIRE 8368 128 8368 48
WIRE 8368 128 7984 128
WIRE 3680 176 3680 64
WIRE 4448 176 4448 112
WIRE 7600 176 7600 64
WIRE 8368 176 8368 128
WIRE 2336 192 2336 128
WIRE 5632 192 5632 80
WIRE 6400 192 6400 128
WIRE 400 208 400 112
WIRE 1008 208 1008 -16
WIRE 1008 208 400 208
WIRE 1376 208 1376 48
WIRE 1376 208 1008 208
WIRE 1008 256 1008 208
WIRE 2336 288 2336 272
WIRE 2704 288 2704 48
WIRE 2704 288 2336 288
WIRE 3680 288 3680 256
WIRE 4448 288 4448 256
WIRE 4448 288 3680 288
WIRE 4704 288 4704 32
WIRE 4704 288 4448 288
WIRE 7600 288 7600 256
WIRE 8368 288 8368 256
WIRE 8368 288 7600 288
WIRE 8624 288 8624 32
WIRE 8624 288 8368 288
WIRE 5632 304 5632 272
WIRE 6400 304 6400 272
WIRE 6400 304 5632 304
WIRE 6656 304 6656 48
WIRE 6656 304 6400 304
WIRE 3680 336 3680 288
WIRE 4448 336 4448 288
WIRE 7600 336 7600 288
WIRE 8368 336 8368 288
WIRE 2336 352 2336 288
WIRE 5632 352 5632 304
WIRE 6400 352 6400 304
WIRE 2336 464 1984 464
WIRE 2400 464 2336 464
WIRE 2528 464 2480 464
WIRE 2704 464 2592 464
WIRE 1984 496 1984 464
WIRE 1984 608 1984 576
WIRE 2336 640 2336 464
WIRE 2000 720 1776 720
WIRE 2208 720 2080 720
WIRE 2288 720 2208 720
WIRE 2704 720 2704 464
WIRE 1776 752 1776 720
WIRE 1776 880 1776 832
WIRE 2336 880 2336 736
WIRE 2336 944 2336 880
WIRE 2336 1040 2336 1024
WIRE 2704 1040 2704 800
WIRE 2704 1040 2336 1040
WIRE 2336 1104 2336 1040
FLAG 1008 256 0
FLAG 656 -144 0
FLAG 2336 352 0
FLAG 1984 -144 0
FLAG 848 -32 Vgs1
FLAG 5632 352 0
FLAG 5280 -144 0
FLAG 6400 352 0
FLAG 7600 336 0
FLAG 7248 -160 0
FLAG 8368 336 0
FLAG 3680 336 0
FLAG 3472 -48 g3
FLAG 3328 -160 0
FLAG 4448 336 0
FLAG 2208 -32 g2
FLAG 2336 128 s2
FLAG 2336 1104 0
FLAG 1984 608 0
FLAG 2208 720 g2_2
FLAG 2336 880 s2_2
FLAG 1776 880 0
FLAG 3680 64 s3
FLAG 4320 -48 g4
FLAG 4448 48 s4
FLAG 5504 -32 g5
FLAG 5632 80 s5
FLAG 6400 128 s6
FLAG 6304 -32 g6
FLAG 7456 -48 g7
FLAG 7600 64 s7
FLAG 8240 -48 g8
FLAG 8368 48 s8
SYMBOL voltage 400 16 R0
WINDOW 3 -41 136 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 15 0 {1/(freq*100)} {1/(freq*100)} {D/freq} {1/freq})
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMBOL current 656 -176 R180
WINDOW 0 24 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName I1
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL voltage 1376 -48 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL diode 1200 -272 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value MyIdealDiode
SYMBOL current 1984 -176 R180
WINDOW 0 24 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName I2
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL voltage 2704 -48 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL diode 2528 -272 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMATTR Value MyIdealDiode
SYMBOL ind 2320 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 100n
SYMBOL nmos 960 -112 R0
SYMATTR InstName M5
SYMATTR Value IRF2807
SYMBOL nmos 2288 -112 R0
SYMATTR InstName M6
SYMATTR Value IRF2807
SYMBOL res 2096 -48 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 12.5
SYMBOL res 768 -48 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 12.5
SYMBOL current 5280 -176 R180
WINDOW 0 24 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName I4
SYMATTR Value 2
SYMBOL voltage 6656 -48 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V7
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL diode 6480 -272 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D4
SYMATTR Value MyIdealDiode
SYMBOL ind 5616 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName L4
SYMATTR Value 10n
SYMBOL res 5136 -48 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL nmos 5584 -112 R0
SYMATTR InstName M1
SYMATTR Value IRF2807
SYMBOL nmos 6352 -112 R0
SYMATTR InstName M2
SYMATTR Value IRF2807
SYMBOL res 5408 -48 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R8
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL res 6144 -48 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R9
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL ind 6384 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName L5
SYMATTR Value 50n
SYMBOL res 6080 112 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R10
SYMATTR Value 1m
SYMBOL current 7248 -192 R180
WINDOW 0 24 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName I5
SYMATTR Value 2
SYMBOL voltage 8624 -64 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V9
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL diode 8448 -288 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D5
SYMATTR Value MyIdealDiode
SYMBOL ind 7584 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName L6
SYMATTR Value 10n
SYMBOL res 7104 -64 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R11
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL nmos 7552 -128 R0
SYMATTR InstName M7
SYMATTR Value IRF2807
SYMBOL nmos 8320 -128 R0
SYMATTR InstName M8
SYMATTR Value IRF2807
SYMBOL res 7376 -64 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R12
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL res 8112 -64 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R13
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL ind 8352 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName L7
SYMATTR Value 50n
SYMBOL res 8000 112 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R14
SYMATTR Value 50m
SYMBOL res 7536 48 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R15
SYMATTR Value 50m
SYMBOL res 5584 64 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R16
SYMATTR Value 1m
SYMBOL current 3328 -192 R180
WINDOW 0 24 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName I3
SYMATTR Value 2
SYMBOL voltage 4704 -64 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V4
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL diode 4528 -288 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D3
SYMATTR Value MyIdealDiode
SYMBOL ind 3664 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName L2
SYMATTR Value 10n
SYMBOL res 3184 -64 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL nmos 3632 -128 R0
SYMATTR InstName M3
SYMATTR Value IRF2807
SYMBOL nmos 4400 -128 R0
SYMATTR InstName M4
SYMATTR Value IRF2807
SYMBOL res 3456 -64 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL res 4192 -64 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL ind 4432 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName L3
SYMATTR Value 10n
SYMBOL res 4128 96 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R7
SYMATTR Value 1m
SYMBOL res 3632 48 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R17
SYMATTR Value 1m
SYMBOL res 2496 -304 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R19
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL voltage 1776 -16 R0
WINDOW 3 -377 136 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 15 0 {1/(freq*100)} {1/(freq*100)} {D/freq} {1/freq})
SYMATTR InstName V5
SYMBOL voltage 2992 -32 R0
WINDOW 3 -122 130 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 15 0 {1/(freq*100)} {1/(freq*100)} {D/freq} {1/freq})
SYMATTR InstName V6
SYMBOL voltage 4944 -16 R0
WINDOW 3 -842 97 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 15 0 {1/(freq*100)} {1/(freq*100)} {D/freq} {1/freq})
SYMATTR InstName V8
SYMBOL voltage 6912 -32 R0
WINDOW 3 -842 97 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 15 0 {1/(freq*100)} {1/(freq*100)} {D/freq} {1/freq})
SYMATTR InstName V10
SYMBOL res 1152 -304 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R18
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL current 1984 576 R180
WINDOW 0 24 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName I6
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL voltage 2704 704 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V11
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL diode 2528 480 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D6
SYMATTR Value MyIdealDiode
SYMBOL ind 2320 928 R0
SYMATTR InstName L8
SYMATTR Value 100n
SYMBOL nmos 2288 640 R0
SYMATTR InstName M9
SYMATTR Value IRF2807
SYMBOL res 2096 704 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R20
SYMATTR Value 12.5
SYMBOL res 2496 448 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R21
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL voltage 1776 736 R0
WINDOW 3 -842 97 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 15 0 {1/(freq*100)} {1/(freq*100)} {D/freq} {1/freq})
SYMATTR InstName V12
TEXT 1000 408 Left 2 !.param freq = 40k D = 0.4
TEXT 1016 456 Left 2 !.tran {5/freq}
TEXT 976 576 Left 2 !.model MySwitch SW(Ron=.1 Roff=1Meg Vt=5 Vh=-10)
TEXT 984 528 Left 2 !.model MyIdealDiode D(Ron=.1 Roff=1Meg Vfwd=.4)
```

Thank you :)

Comment: In similar situations using inductors in TRANSIENT simulations, adding even a tiny bit of series resistance to an inductor satisfies convergence. A bit of series resistance is realistic as well.

Comment: Try adding a high-value resistance from the FET drains to ground, such as 10MEG.

Comment: At least with RF circuits and BJTs, putting an inductor between the emitter and ground can make a common-emitter circuit go unstable.  FETs aren't _that_ different -- you may have just designed yourself an oscillator.  On the other hand, you're driving the FET pretty hard, so it shouldn't have a chance to take off on its own.  I'd take the suggestion give the inductor a realistic series resistance and see how things go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few solutions:

- Add parasitics ([@Voltage Spike's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/642865/95619), though it's a pure `.model`, not a `.subckt`). For best results add all three parasitics, e.g. `Rpar=1k Cpar=0.1p Rser=1m` (default). At the minimum add `Cpar` but, that will likely not give very impressive results. `RCpar, Rpar` will be better. `Rser` is a bit optional, the default will likely be enough.
- Change the solver to gear. The best way to do it is to add `.opt method=gear` (optional `maxord=2...6`), which can be commented out easily, without the fear that the Control Panel setting might still be there on future simulations (e.g. it will only be active, or not, for the current schematic). The reason is the modified trap solver and how it "thinks". If you plot `V(s2)` you'll see that the voltage rises and then suddenly drops with a very sharp edge. That is bound to cause discontinuities and the trapezoidal solver has some problems with it (see the help under *LTspice > Integration Methods* for an explanation though, [it doesn't really do it for me](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/596138/95619)).
- Use LTspice prior to May 2019 or LTspice IV (sadly, even the BETA version has artifacts).

Comment: Forgot to say that the Gear solver will dampen everything, even if you don't want it to (it's a side effect that comes "with the territory").

Comment: What is the difference between may2019 and now?

Comment: @VoltageSpike  Click on the "it doesn't really do it for me" link.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @VoltageSpike There has been a change around that time that caused the bug seen in the link above. Whatever the cause, the effects are wrong readings sometimes, plus various opinions about it: not everyone sees it as a bug (e.g. like me).

Answer (score 4):

Some of the IRF MOSFET models are weird with some containing dependent sources, and can give the solver issues in situations.

The problem is you're using a superconducting inductor you need to make it more like the real world. Add some series resistance to the inductor and possibly some high resistance parallel resistance or capacitance.

[image]

If you replace the inductor with the resistor and the simulation still has issues it's probably the model

Comment: Looks to me like the IRF2807 being used is the built-in VDMOS model, which is not a subcircuit,

Comment: I wasn't sure on that one, but I've had a few IRF models that do have dependent sources.